# Conditional fields in views drupal 6

Tags: views

I am using conditional field in content type.

Is it possible to do the same in views 
i want to show one field dependent on value of first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Views Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/views_conditional) is a simple module that allows you to define conditionals (if xxx then yyy)
with fields in views.

> Conditions include:
>
> - Equal To
> - Not Equal To
> - Greater Than
> - Less Than
> - Empty
> - Not Empty

**For D6**

[Views - Control field display](https://drupal.org/project/views_control_field_display)

> It provides a views filter that allows users to control which fields
>   are displayed.
>
> To use, install the module, then add the Global: Control field
>   **visibility filter** to your view. Select which fields are controllable
>   (either defaulting to visible or invisible). This will add an exposed
>   element that allows users to toggle the fields you specify on or off.

Comment: i need in drupal 6 not for 7 .

Comment: It in dev, but you can use https://drupal.org/project/views_ifempty

Comment: I updated my answer